# Non-English identifiers in \label / \ref ("Missing \endcsname inserted")

Tags: cross-referencing, characters

I found that LaTeX chokes on certain non-ASCII identifiers in `\ref`.

This works fine:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Foobär}
\label{sec:Foobär}

See \ref{sec:Foobär}

\end{document}
```

The same thing with "Barbaß" instead of "Foobär" aborts with "Missing \endcsname inserted." (huh?).

Now, the naive sollution would be "don't use non-ASCII identifiers", of course. But since I'm using some macro magic to get labels auto-defined by section headers / table captions, as well as generating some surrounding text for references, I would *really* like to use native language in labels, instead of crimping them into ASCII-7.

Any way to get this done?

Comment: `Barbaß` works with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Other than feeding both the argument of `\label` and of `\ref` to `\detokenize` there isn't much you can do with standard LaTeX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd edition:

> 2.4 Managing references
>
> [...]   To allow cross-referencing of elements inside a document, you
>   should assign a `key` (consisting of a string of ASCII letters,
>   digits, and punctuation) to the given structural element and then use
>   that key to refer to that element elsewhere.
>
> ```
> \label{key}  \ref{key}  \pageref{key}
> ```

Technically the `key` should survive `\csname...\endcsname`. Package `babel` makes some punctuation active as shorthand characters, but it patches the referencing system to allow shorthands inside keys. That can be used to redefine `\IeC` that is an internal wrapper for the Unicode letters of `utf8.def`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\IeC}{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \if@safe@actives
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\IeC@detokenize
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
  \else
    \noexpand\IeC
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\IeC@detokenize}[1]{\detokenize{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Barbaß}
\label{sec:Barbaß}

See \ref{sec:Barbaß}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes you're braver than I am:-) I chickened out of redefining IeC and made a new command instead, but then I had to redefine ref to use it, so probably redefining IeC is better in the end:-) apart from that we both just added \detokenize (which wasn't available when we did inputenc as we were restricting to tex3 at the time)

Comment: Looks like something that should find its way into the proper packages somehow...

Comment: Sheesh, will you **look** at this: Heiko's solution works fine. But if I add `\usepackage{thumbs}` to the preamble, and `\begin{titlepage} \begin{center} Foo \end{center} \end{titlepage}` to the body, the same error pops up again. That's probably the most illogical way-to-reproduce I've posted so far, but there it is. :-D Anyway, that is hardly Heiko's fault, so this is the accepted answer.

Comment: @DevSolar I could not reproduce the problem with package `thumbs`.

Answer (score 11):

Hmm This seems to work, adding a bit of extra etex to the latex protection mechanism:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

\def\IeCb#1{\string\IeCb{\detokenize{#1}}}
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{\let\IeC\IeCb}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}

\let\oldref\ref
\protected\def\ref#1{\let\IeC\IeCb\oldref{#1}}

\let\oldpageref\pageref
\protected\def\pageref#1{\let\IeC\IeCb\oldpageref{#1}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Foobärß}
\label{sec:Foobärß}

See \ref{sec:Foobärß}

\end{document}
```